# Possible to set Facebook Likebox Posts background to transparent?

Tags: html, css, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-likebox

How can I change the background color on the posts section of the Facebook Likebox?

I can change the likebox background but not the posts. If I use chrome developer tools and set .mbm class to have "background-color: transparent" then it works.

However this will not take affect if I include it in my css. Even with !important

Perhaps it's something to do with the posts being loaded externally?

I'm using this Facebook plugin:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages

With the HTML5 option

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers" data-colorscheme="dark" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="true" data-show-border="true"></div>
```

EDIT: jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/y4gwE/

Included a screenshot for clarity, highlighting the background color I'm wanting to change

[image: FB LikeBox]

Comment: +1 your highlighting style made me laugh (in a good manner)

Comment: Use the Developer Tool of your browser and have a look at the code. Then add a style rule to your CSS file for setting the background color to transparent - that's it!

Comment: @Netsurfer Tried that, no luck. See my jsfiddle in case I'm doing something wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/y4gwE/

Comment: @user3348273 AFAIS it is the class `._4-u2`. But there are two other problems: Firstly the respective code is inserted in an iframe, which means that any styles have to be inline in the document which is loaded into that frame. Or in an external style sheet loaded by this document. And secondly, if the user scrolls down in the posts, more posts seem to be loaded what also seems to 'reload' the style rules bundled with it. So you would need to do a lot of Javascript work to achieve your goal. Might not be worth it ...!

Answer (score 1):

Just to be totally super-duper sure, try really ramping up the specificity in your CSS:

```
iframe html#facebook .mbm {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```